# Weird Persistence Exception thrown at deployment time

Tags: java, gwt, glassfish, materialize, gwt-material-design

I have a gradle Material GWT Project setup. The projects builds just fine, and for some time now everything has been peachy. Not until I changed the dependencies for Material GWT from 1.6.0 to 2.0-rc3, and GWT itself from 2.7.0 to 2.8.0. I needed these because of the new widgets on Material GWT 2.0 and above. Upon deployment to Payara (glassfish 4) I get this exception, and deployment fails.

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [myFunApp] : 
Exception [EclipseLink-23004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.TransactionException
Exception Description: Error obtaining the Transaction Manager
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-23001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.TransactionException
Exception Description: Error looking up external Transaction resource under JNDI name [java:appserver/TransactionManager]
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'appserver/TransactionManager'
```

I have seen [Glassfish v4 Transaction Manager not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738354/glassfish-v4-transaction-manager-not-found) link where @Arun Gupta answers a similar question, but it makes no sense to me at all. Any ideas would really be helpful. I should point out that changing the dependencies work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never resolved this issue. But I have a nice workaround. The said project (Gradle, with Material GWT) was actually a single project. Separating the project into three projects, namely Client, API, and Commons projects, I was able to deploy the API separately to the same Glassfish Server as the Client. This separation somehow helped.